# iOS Address Book Import Crash Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, objective-c

First a quick background, I hired a developer to build my app however I know that I learn better by dissecting existing code so my goal is to learn more about iOS programming this way rather than paying the developer to fix.

Now, the app is crashing when I am importing a contact from the address book into the app. I have noticed that the app crash happens when I import a contact from the iOS Facebook contacts but not other groups of contacts. What could be causing this?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
```

Research tells me that the app is trying to call something it does not have access to but not sure where to go from here.

Here is the area of code that I believe is causing the issue. (This action).

```
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker{
[_addressBookController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
_arrContactsData =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *contactInfoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                        initWithObjects:@[@"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @""]
                                        forKeys:@[@"firstName", @"lastName", @"mobileNumber", @"homeNumber", @"homeEmail", @"workEmail", @"address", @"zipCode", @"city"]];

// Use a general Core Foundation object.
CFTypeRef generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

// Get the first name.
if (generalCFObject) {
    [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject forKey:@"firstName"];
    CFRelease(generalCFObject);
}

// Get the last name.
generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
if (generalCFObject) {
    [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject forKey:@"lastName"];
    CFRelease(generalCFObject);
}

// Get the phone numbers as a multi-value property.
ABMultiValueRef phonesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
for (int i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(phonesRef); i++) {
    CFStringRef currentPhoneLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phonesRef, i);
    CFStringRef currentPhoneValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonesRef, i);

    if (CFStringCompare(currentPhoneLabel, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentPhoneValue forKey:@"mobileNumber"];
    }

    if (CFStringCompare(currentPhoneLabel, kABHomeLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentPhoneValue forKey:@"homeNumber"];
    }

    CFRelease(currentPhoneLabel);
    CFRelease(currentPhoneValue);
}
CFRelease(phonesRef);


// Get the e-mail addresses as a multi-value property.
ABMultiValueRef emailsRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
for (int i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(emailsRef); i++) {
    CFStringRef currentEmailLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emailsRef, i);
    CFStringRef currentEmailValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailsRef, i);

    if (CFStringCompare(currentEmailLabel, kABHomeLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentEmailValue forKey:@"homeEmail"];
    }

    if (CFStringCompare(currentEmailLabel, kABWorkLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentEmailValue forKey:@"workEmail"];
    }

    CFRelease(currentEmailLabel);
    CFRelease(currentEmailValue);
}
CFRelease(emailsRef);


// Get the first street address among all addresses of the selected contact.
ABMultiValueRef addressRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(addressRef) > 0) {
    NSDictionary *addressDict = (__bridge NSDictionary *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressRef, 0);

    [contactInfoDict setObject:[addressDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey] forKey:@"address"];
    [contactInfoDict setObject:[addressDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey] forKey:@"zipCode"];
    [contactInfoDict setObject:[addressDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey] forKey:@"city"];
}
CFRelease(addressRef);


// If the contact has an image then get it too.
if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
    NSData *contactImageData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

    [contactInfoDict setObject:contactImageData forKey:@"image"];
}

// Initialize the array if it's not yet initialized.
if (_arrContactsData == nil) {
    _arrContactsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
// Add the dictionary to the array.
[_arrContactsData addObject:contactInfoDict];

// Reload the table view data.


// Dismiss the address book view controller.
[_addressBookController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
NSDictionary *info = [_arrContactsData objectAtIndex:0];
self.txfFirstName.text = [info objectForKey:@"firstName"];
self.txfLastName.text = [info objectForKey:@"lastName"];
self.txfMobile.text =[info objectForKey:@"mobileNumber"];
self.txfEmail.text =[info objectForKey:@"homeEmail"];
NSLog(@"Info %@",info);

return NO;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about the crash - where in your app does it crash (which line of code)?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint from the breakpoint navigator to help locate the line causing the crash

Comment: @rmaddy Ok thanks. The breakpoint is at:
    if (CFStringCompare(currentEmailLabel, kABHomeLabel, 0) ==     kCFCompareEqualTo) {

Comment: Starting to come together. Looking at a Facebook contact they do not have a home or work email but a 'Facebook' type email. If I add a home email to contact the app does not crash.

Comment: The code is pretty horrible.  I don't know why they are using the CF classes rather than the more conventional NSString etc.  I suspect that the problem is probably being caused by passing a null pointer to CFStringCompare.  You either need to guard the call by first checking if the value is null or (better) refactor to use NSString and then you can safely call `[currentEmailLabel isEqualToString:kABHomeLabel]` as Objective C doesn't throw an exception if you invoke a method on a nil object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Facebook labels its email contacts weird in the address book, so that when you query the labels it returns a nil value, which will give you your bad access error and the crash

personally i put an if statement around it and just ignored all nil addresses as i only wanted work addresses anyway, see following example in your code (i haven't checked this but it should work)

After "analyzing" my previous answer I noticed that it actually reported a memory leak so i moved the if around a bit and with the updated code below its gone.

```
for (int i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(emailsRef); i++) {

    CFStringRef currentEmailLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emailsRef, i);
    CFStringRef currentEmailValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailsRef, i);

    if (currentEmailLabel != nil) {

        if (CFStringCompare(currentEmailLabel, kABWorkLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
            [self.contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentEmailValue forKey:@"workEmail"];
        }
        CFRelease(currentEmailLabel);
    }

    CFRelease(currentEmailValue);
}
CFRelease(emailsRef);//END OF IF WRAPPER
```

if you want the emails and don't care that they are Facebook I imagine you could just do a nil check on the label and relabel it or just ignore the label compare completely.

Comment: While checking a CFStringRef against nil should work, I think it is actually wrong semantically and should be checked against NULL instead.